# Not able to decode vcard which contains french characters?

Tags: c++, c, sms-gateway, smpp, telecommunication

I need to encode `=C3=AA=74=65=64` string but not getting the correct characters as sent from mobile.

```
BEGIN:VCARD^M
VERSION:2.1^M
N;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:;=C3=AA=74=65=64;;;^M
FN;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTAABLE:=C3=AA=74=65=64^M
TEL;CELL;PREF:75501945^M
END:VCARD^M
```

I have encoded from `iso8859-1` to `CP850` using iconv but getting the same characters after conversion.

Please suggest
Thanks in advance

Comment: string sent from mobile is êted

Comment: This looks like UTF-8 (`ê` is `0xC3 0xAA` under that encoding).

Comment: how should i encode it using iconv function of linux?

Comment: Pass `"UTF-8"` as the second argument to `iconv_open()`.

Comment: first argument as ISO8859-1?

Comment: First argument is your output encoding, only you know what it should be :)

Comment: but manual command is not working : echo "=C3=AA=74=65=64" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-1

Comment: I did not realize you were passing the raw quoted-printable string. You will have to decode this into UTF-8 beforehand, then convert the result into your encoding of choice.

Comment: you mean that i need to convert it into utf-8 first and then to my own encoding?

Comment: but how should i convert it into utf-8, i think using iconv, then what should be the second argument in that case

Comment: 0x02 is the encoding scheme of the smsc